# How to create an ObservableList from a list of keys?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to show all the "exercises" belonging to a user. Because an "exercise" object can belong to multiple users, this is a typical many-to-many relationship. Since the docs suggest to flatten the structure of the database, each user has a dictionary of `{ $exercise_key: true }`.

After hours of searching, I finally got something that works, but it is ugly and seems pretty slow and inefficient. I first get an observable list of the exercise keys from the user, then for each of those keys, I get a FirebaseObservableObject that I attach as a 'metadata' attribute.

When I load the page, first I see a list of empty bullets, then only half of the bullets get their text, then finally the rest. The whole thing takes ~2 seconds to show. This "flicker" happens even when I add a new exercise dynamically, without reloading the page. Please try it by yourself on https://papa-bear-1f486.firebaseapp.com (use google auth).

My database looks like this:

```
{
  "exercises" : {
    "-KeVLI3UbGkRbifLffMa" : {
      "createdAt" : 1488748884471,
      "name" : "squat1"
    },
    "-KeVLISTWaXbFxS6yqfv" : {
      "createdAt" : 1488748886066,
      "name" : "squat2"
    },
  },
  "users" : {
    "JtLTkOb8EXTeCeasF6vLpIpoUDB2" : {
      "exercises" : {
        "-KeVLI3UbGkRbifLffMa" : true,
        "-KeVLISTWaXbFxS6yqfv" : true,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the ugly code I came up with:

```
private exercisesKey$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
private exercises$: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private af: AngularFire, private auth: AuthService) {
  const path = '/users/' + auth.id + '/exercises';

  this.exercisesKey$ = af.database.list(path);
  this.exercises$ = this.exercisesKey$.map((items) => {
    items.map(item => {
      item.metadata = this.getExercise(item.$key);
      return item;
    });
  return items;
});

getExercise(key: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<IExercise> {
    return this.af.database.object('/exercises/' + key);
}
```

And in my view:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let exercise of exerciseService.exercises$ | async">
    {{ (exercise.metadata | async)?.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

So I guess my question is: **how to get an observable list of objects created from a list of keys?**

package.json:

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
"firebase": "^3.5.2",
```

Comment: You should consider updating your AngularFire2 dependency, as there have been numerous bug fixes since the version you are using.

Comment: In addition to cartant's comments, it shouldn't be necessary for you to use the async pipe in both your ngFor expression and your interpolated value. My understanding is that you'd only use it in the ngFor expression in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do to avoid a query for each exercise (unless you want to perform a single query that retrieves every exercise). However, you can simplify things a little.

You can use `combineLatest` to compose an observable of exercises:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

constructor(private af: AngularFire, private auth: AuthService) {
  const path = '/users/' + auth.id + '/exercises';
  this.exercisesKey$ = af.database.list(path);
  this.exercises$ = this.exercisesKey$
    .switchMap((items) => items.length === 0 ?
      Observable.of([]) :
      Observable.combineLatest(...items.map(item => this.getExercise(item.$key)));
    );
});
```

If the list of exercise keys changes or if an exercise itself changes, the composed observable will re-emit the list of exercises.

If you want only a snapshot of the exercises and don't want an observable that re-emits if an exercise changes, use `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest` and use `first` to complete each exercise observable:

```js
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

constructor(private af: AngularFire, private auth: AuthService) {
  const path = '/users/' + auth.id + '/exercises';
  this.exercisesKey$ = af.database.list(path);
  this.exercises$ = this.exercisesKey$
    .switchMap((items) => items.length === 0 ?
      Observable.of([]) :
      Observable.forkJoin(...items.map(item => this.getExercise(item.$key).first()));
    );
});
```

In both cases your template would look something like this:

```js
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let exercise of exerciseService.exercises$ | async">
    {{ exercise.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @cartant, very helpful!